# Проблема с фоном - StyleSheet Qt

Tags: c++, qt

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]Я создал класс наследующий от QWidget. Хотел добавить к нему фон при помощи StyleSheet, но почему-то в этот фон раскрашиваются кнопки и Label которые находятся на этом QWidget-е. Можете объяснить почему и/или сказать что надо сделать чтобы нормально поставить фон?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Все правильно, т.к. объекты находятся в QWidget то они берут его StyleSheet. 
Решение: Просто укажи StyleSheet для кнопок и label.
Я обычно делаю border:none;